# UML creator for Java / Android in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, uml

I need an free UML creator that can automatically create an UML for an Android Project. the most I could find does not really work with classes I used in my project like services, fragments and so on..  is there any tool that can do it?

Comment: Andorid or Java... Use `PlantUML`.